# How to get a single value from a Dictionary<Key,Value> given a property that belongs to the type Value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, lambda

Let's say I have this dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Guid, Person> people = new Dictionary<Guid, Person>();
```

Assume it's populated with some data. Let's also say `Person` has a `Ssn` property. I would like to return the Person in people with `Ssn = socialSecurityNum` where `socialSecurityNum` is some value. This is the best idea I have to do this:

```
public Person GetPerson(int socialSecurityNum) 
{
    IEnumerable<Person> persons = people.Values.Where(p => p.SSN == socialSecurityNum);
    foreach (Person person in persons)
    {
        return person;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I know that each person will have a different `Ssn`, so I just return whatever value is first in the list (since the list is just one value). Otherwise return null.

The thing I don't like about this solution is that I have to get a list from the linq query as opposed to a single value. Is there a linq query that can get a single value from the dictionary?

Comment: Usually, you try to design your code so that you don't have inefficient code like that...

Comment: @Phil1970 do you mind elaborating? I'd like to improve my code whenever I can, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: Well, if you have 1000000 peoples, you have to check all of them if there are no people with that social security number. Usually, you would store the data in a database and have an index for that column and then write a query to get that people alone.  **Essentially, you try to avoid algorithm that are O(n) for search if possible**. By the way how the Guid is related to SSN. Maybe, the dictionary should use the SSN as the key.

Comment: @Phil1970 Ah I see, thanks. This was actually just an example since I didn't want to make the question too contrived with what I'm actually working with. The dictionary will be at most a dozen or two entries big, so I think this approach will be fine. But thanks for the advice for when it's larger, and I guess I should have specified that in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `Where` use `FirstOrDefault`

```
return people.Values.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SSN == socialSecurityNum);
```

Comment: Duh, thanks. I don't know why that didn't occur to me.

Comment: @Drew, no problem :)

Comment: @Drew it happens to best of us

Comment: Consider SingleOrDefault if you want an exception in the exceptional case that there is more than one people with socialSecurityNum

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse, according to the question, `FirstOrDefault` is exactly what OP wants